# How to get the output of jq in single line?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jq

I have used jq with aws cli to print the instances .
Eg: 
**Retrieve instances list**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:bld_env,Values=test" --output json > all-inst.json
```

Jq to print instances id :

```
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' all-inst.json
```

Output of Jq:

```
 i-09e0d805cc 
 i-091a61038 
 i-07d3022
 i-0428ac7c4c
 i-970dc5c4d99 
 i-014c4ea
 i-0ac924df
 i-031f6 and so on..
```

I want to print them in a line like this :

```
i-09e0d805cc,i-091a61038,i-07d3022,i-0428ac7c4c,i-970dc5c4d99,i-014c4ea,i-0ac924df,i-031f6 and so on..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the angle bracket characters really there? Otherwise you can simply `tr '\n' ','`.

Comment: I have edited the description. How can I add this with jq, along with the command i have shared above ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some jq-only approaches.

It's often simplest just to "join" the lines (e.g. using `join(",")`). This is typically done with the `-r` command-line option.

In cases where this is impractical or inefficient, one can use the `--join` (or `-j`) command-line option.  Here are two illustrations using this approach.  In neither of the examples does the output include a newline.

#### With a terminating comma

```
jq -n -j 'range(0;5) | "\(.),"'
```

#### Without a terminating comma

oneline.jq:

```
def oneline(f):
  foreach f as $i (null;
    if . == null then "\($i)" else ",\($i)" end;
    .);

oneline( range(0;5) )
```

Invocation: jq -n -j -f oneline.jq

Output:

```
0,1,2,3,4
```