# Replace \n with space in jq query/command output without tr and sed commands

Tags: bash, shell, unix, filter, jq

The below is my input file, say input.json

```
{
  "server1": {
    "name": "server1",
    "property": "ENABLED"
  },
  "server2": {
    "name": "server2",
    "property": "ENABLED"
  },
  "server3": {
    "name": "server3",
    "property": "ENABLED"
  },
  "server4": {
    "name": "server4",
    "property": "ENABLED"
  },
  "server5": {
    "name": "server5",
    "property": "ENABLED"
  },
  "server6": {
    "name": "server6",
    "property": "ENABLED"
  }
}
```

I am running the following jq query:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.property == "ENABLED") |.name' input.json
```

I get the below output:

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
server6
```

I want my output to be without any new line and as below, separated by space and no space after the last word (server6 in this case)

```
server1 server2 server3 server4 server5 server6
```

I don't want to do pipe after jq command and obtain the output with sed and tr commands. I want to achieve this with jq command only. Would appreciate the help. thanks.

Comment: Not sure if they're actual duplicates, but they seem close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133851/how-to-get-the-output-of-jq-in-single-line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131727/printing-multiple-values-on-the-same-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close to there! In your case, the `join` function may help:

```sh
jq -r '[.[]|select(.property=="ENABLED")|.name]|join(" ")' input.json
```

By wrapping all names in an array, the `join` function works like that in python. From the doc:

> join(str)
>
> Joins the array of elements given as input, using the argument as separator. It is the inverse of split: that  is,  running
> split("foo") | join("foo") over any input string returns said input string.
>
> ```
> jq ´join(", ")´
>    ["a","b,c,d","e"]
> => "a, b,c,d, e"
> ```

Comment: awesome. I tried join before but it did not give me the output I expected because I had not wrapped it in an array. Thank you.